# Caching Compiled Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, compilation

Is there a way to access and possibly cache the output of a browser's compilation of Javascript? Seem like that could be a tremendous performance booster.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not a compiled language, it's a script... (executed line by line)